# Creating address using Clef JSON-RPC without manual Confirmation on Clef

Tags: blockchain, ether, json-rpc, nodes, external-api

I am trying to create a new account using clef on my ETH node. I am using clef JSON-RPC

`{"id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "account_new", "params": []}`

But everytime i run this api call, the operation hands until i verify this from clef cli window .
[image]

I have tried creating a rule that returns approve for all cases

```
function ApproveTx() {
    return "Approve";
}
function ApproveListing() {
    return "Approve";    
}
```

I have attested the rule using

`> clef attest .clef/rules.js`

I need to understand how i can bypass this manual confirmation on clef for account_new.